# Primitive array validation with vuelidate

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vuelidate

I'm using vuelidate 2.0 to validate a form.

I'm trying to validate a primitive array, and I can't find a way to do it.

When using `helpers.forEach({ required })` it works perfectly with array of objects, but it doesn't seem to be working with array of primitives.

For example form values can be:

```
  const values = reactive({
     name: "",
     labels: []
  })
```

Is there a way we can define `labels` validation?

I have tried to use:

```
  const validations = {
      name: { required },
      labels: {
         minLength: minLength(2),
         $each: helpers.forEach({
          required,
        }),
      }
  }
```

But it seems to be working only on `labels` and not for each.
So what happens is that if I have less than 2 items in the array, I get the correct error, but each item is not getting the required error as should.

Comment: can you please provide the vue html part and optimally a reproduction link on jsfiddle. Please be also specific if you use vue 3 or vue 2